# Is there an extra cost to cache misses on Redis

Tags: redis

Is there an advantage to set a default value for an entry that will be heavily queried in Redis or will querying for the unset key take the same time?

Given the keys are stored in a distributed hash, it will have to check that the key is not in the bucket before returning on a miss, which may be a bit slower than finding and stopping at a hit. Is the bucket sorted of linear? Does anything else make it slower either way?

Redis is setup in a cluster and has many million entries in this case.

Comment: I think it is O(1) for searching for the redis instance, and another O(1) for locating the actual key cuz it is all hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're just talking about strings & hashes here here (so the only operations you care about are set/get, maybe hget/hset) - From Redis' perspective, a cache hit and cache miss have the same time complexity, if anything, a cache miss will be faster because redis will not have to transfer any data back over the socket to your app.